# Название прохода в парк

Tags: лексика

Как назвать проход в парк, изображённый на фотографии? Можно ли его назвать аркой (несмотря на то, что он длинный), коридором или галереей?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Это можно назвать **арочной аллеей**.

https://green-fil.ru/ozelenenie/alleya

В узком смысле (когда смыкание наверху создано искусственным *навесом* под вьющиеся растения) употребляется термин итальянского происхождения **пергола** (см. википедию на это слово).